# junctionIdList on junction object (Starting in API version 34.0)

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to understand and learn the way junctionIdList works in Salesforce and its potential benefits.

This Salesforce documentation describes it as a Field (Data) Type : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/field_types.htm

I have created an example of a junction object for me to verify if this field (junctionIdList) appears and can be queried (SOQL) but the field does not appear as part of the list of available fields that can be queried.

Questions:

A) What is this JunctionIdList field for?
B) Should I expect it to be automatically created by Salesforce on Junction Objects?
C) Is it automatically populated by Salesforce?
D) Could you provide an example of a good way to leverage this junctionIdList field?

Thank you very much.